# Parse an Array into a Recycler view from Json with Retrofit

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Hello i am practicing my kotlin skills with retrofit and recycler views, and i found this type of data in some JSON i found for my practice

```
"capital":[
          "Montevideo"

]
```

I know this is an array, and i was able to parse it to my Recyler View  by declaring in my data class that capital is a List  like this:

```
data class Country(

    val name: Name,
    val cioc: String,
    val independent: Boolean,
    val region: String,
    val capital: List<String>
)

data class Name(
    val common: String,
    val official: String,

)
```

I made things normal in my adapter like this

```
class CountryAdapter(val countries: List<Country>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CountriesViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CountriesViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerline, parent, false)
        return CountriesViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return countries.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountriesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        return holder.bind(countries[position])

    }
}

class CountriesViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    private val officialName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo)
    private val independent: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo2)
    private val capital: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo3)





    fun bind(country: Country) {

        //Integer.parseInt

      //  val sum = (user.id + user.id).toString()
        officialName.text = country.name.official //user.address.geo.lat + " / " + user.address.geo.lng
        independent.text = "Independent: " + country.independent.toString()
        capital.text = country.capital.toString()


    }

}
```

However in my Recycler view, the result for the capital  is appearing  like  [Montevideo]  instead of just Montevideo.   How do i take  the [] out from the visual result?

[image: How my recycler appears]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capital is a list so doing a toString() on a list will give you a string of an array like this : "[a,b,c,d,e]".

If you want to print the first item you can just get it and use toString on it : `country.capital?.get(0)?.toString()`.

If you want to print the entire list without the hooks you can use [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) method like this :

```
country.capital.joinToString(" ")
```

The first parameter is the separator, here I simply used a space between each items but you can separate them with any strings.

Answer (score 1):

Change this in fun bind(country: Country):

```
capital.text = country.capital.toString().drop(1).dropLast(1)

//or

capital.text = country.capital[0]
```

Comment: Thank you!  Despite Working,  @Dinamots answer fills better my needs